# Definition of $k$-times differentiable on $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

I'm trying to come up with a good definition of being $k$-times differentiable on a subset $S$.

Here's the definitions I'm working with.

Let $f$ be a function from $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $L\in\mathbb{R}$. If $x_0\in X$ is a limit point of $X$, we say that $f$ has derivative $L$ at $x_0$ iff $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=L$, i.e. iff
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-L\right\rvert<\epsilon.$$

If $S$ is a subset of $X$, we say that $f$ is differentiable on $S$ iff the derivative exists at $x_0$ for all $x_0\in S$ (in particular, every point of $S$ must be a limit point of $X$). We say that $f$ is differentiable iff it is differentiable on its whole domain.

**Are these definitions standard so far?**

Now the definition I've come upon for "$k$-times differentiable" is as follows.

Let $f$ be a function from $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We say that $f$ is $1$-times differentiable iff $f$ is differentiable, and the first derivative of $f$ is the function $f^{'}:X\to\mathbb{R}$, also denoted $f^{(1)}$, defined in the obvious way. For $k\geq 1$, we say that $f$ is $(k+1)$-times differentiable iff $f$ is $k$-times differentiable and $f^{(k)}$ is differentiable, and in this case the $(k+1)$th derivative is the function $f^{(k+1)}:= (f^{(k)})': X\to\mathbb{R}$. A function is said to be infinitely differentiable iff it is $k$-times differentiable for all $k$.

Seem fine so far? But then I thought, how would I say that a function $f$ is $k$-times differentiable on some subset of its domain? Well, since we want "$f$ is $1$-times differentiable" to mean the same as "$f$ is differentiable", we might want "$f$ is $1$-times differentiable on $S$" to mean the same as "$f$ is differentiable on $S$".
**How would you define "$f$ is $k$-times differentiable on $S$"**?

Comment: You are essentially inducting on the order of the derivative of $f$. if you want this definition to be differentiable on $S\subseteq X$, then i would add in the conditions you have provided for being differentiable on $S$ one time and apply it to each successive derivative on $S$.

Comment: For clarity, you should wrote $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \, \exists \delta \gt 0: \, \forall x \in X: 0 \lt |x-x_0| \lt \delta ~ \Longrightarrow \ldots$ in your definition of the derivative al limit point $x_0 \in X$. I mean all $x$ should be taken from the oversection of $X$ and punctured $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can define "$f$ is differentiable on $S$" as you do. Higher derivatives are then a problem. For example, if $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in S$, we are in general not able to define $f''(x)$ for $x \in S$ because we cannnot be sure that each $x \in S$ is a be a limit point of $S$. You could do it as follows:

Define $f$ to be *$k$-times differentiable on $S$* if there exist subsets $S_i \subset X$, $0=1,\ldots,k$, such that

1. $S = S_k \subset S_{k-1} \subset \ldots S_2 \subset S_1 \subset S_0 = X$
2. Each $x \in S_{i+1} $ is a limit point of $S_i$, $i =1,\ldots, k$
3. $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in S_1$, $f''(x)$ exists for all $x \in S_2$, etc.

But honestly I do not think this concept is very useful.

Comment: Ok this is similar to what I came up with as well. I just wanted a more experienced second opinion. Basically for an arbitrary function $g$ one can define a derivative function $g':A\to\mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is the set of points for which the derivative exists. Then we define $g^{(1)}=g'$ and $g^{(k+1)}=(g^{(k)})'$ and we say $g$ is $k$-times differentiable on $S$ iff $S$ is a subset of the domain of $g^{(k)}$.