# Definition of function, differentiable on $S \subset X$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

Some textbooks give the following definition of the derivative of a function at point $x_0$:

> Let's consider a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, a point $x_0 \in X$ - some limit point of $X$, and a real function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Then the derivative of $f$ at point $x_0$ is the following limit (if it exists and finite):
> $\displaystyle f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0 \\ x \in X} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$

I think that we can easily build the natural generalization of this definition for a some subset $S \subset X \subset \mathbb{R}$.
Let's call a real function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable on a set $S \subset X \subset \mathbb{R}$ if all points of $S$ are limit points of $S$ and in every point $x_0 \in S$ the derivative of $f$ exists, i.e:

$\displaystyle \forall x_0 \in S ~\hookrightarrow~ f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0 \\ x \in S} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Is this definition correct? If so, why is it never mentioned in textbooks?** (at least I have never seen attempts to give such definition; I have seen definitions only for specific sets $S$, like $S=[a,b]$ or $S = (a,b)$, but not for an arbitrary set $S$)

---

There is a [post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901351/definition-of-k-times-differentiable-on-s) where the very similar definition of the differentiable function on a set $S \subset X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is given. But it has one difference from the definition above – it requires that "every point of $S$ must be a limit point of $X$". I think this is wrong requirement because we need more stronger requirement that "every point of $S$ must be a limit point of $S$".

Comment: Two examples where this formulation is used: [path derivative](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22path+derivative%22+Bruckner) and [cone differentiability](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cone+differentiability%22). Here's a 1907 paper where this notion is studied: [*On derivatives over assemblages*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1907-008-03/S0002-9947-1907-1500788-X/) by Earle Raymond Hedrick. And directional derivatives for multivariable functions is a common elementary example.